# Ignore formula on brew upgrade

Tags: homebrew

I want to do a `brew upgrade` and tell homebrew do not upgrade the `erlang` formula since the latest one does not work on my system.

Is it possible do do something like `homebrew upgrade --skip erlang`?

Comment: See the modern version of this question that was asked long after `brew pin` was removed from Homebrew:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435901/homebrew-how-to-ignore-formula-on-brew-upgrade-since-pin-was-removed

Answer (score 188, accepted):

I finally found an answer: since commit [85eb73ce][1] there is a `pin` subcommand available. So ignoring a formula on `brew upgrade` is as simple as pinning it via `brew pin <formula>`. To un-pin it, simply invoke `brew unpin <formula>`.

It is worth noting that `brew upgrade <formula>` will still update the formula regardless of whether or not it is pinned.

Comment: If you ask yourself one day what formulas you pinned: [`brew list --pinned`](http://superuser.com/a/912406/215109)

Comment: Euh, what is the point of pinning if `brew upgrade` will still update the formula...?

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan, if I understand correct, it excludes pinned formulas from cumulative upgrade in a group.

Comment: This does not work for casks.  Is there any alternative that would be analogous to `brew pin caskName`?

Comment: The caveat in the answer is invalid. `brew pin` is a valid command.

Answer (score 51):

brew pin is the way to go. It will pin the formula to the current version

`brew pin <formula>`

brew unpin can be used to reset this

`brew unpin <formula>`

To view all *pinned* formulae

`brew list --pinned`

**Note:** `brew upgrade` will not upgrade pinned formulae.

Comment: FWIW pin and unpin work in the current Homebrew version, 3.3.13.

Answer (score 7):

You could upgrade erlang to the latest version but keep using the older working version with the brew commands `versions` and `switch`.

To list available versions use:

```
brew versions erlang
```

To switch between two installed versions (I'll presume you wanted erlang R14):

```
brew switch erlang R14B04
```

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar 'problem'. i installed libfreenect (unstable) directly on my system. and now i dont want homebrew to upgrade it. i solved it by deleting following file:

`/usr/local/Library/Formula/libfreenect.rb`

analogous it would be `/usr/local/Library/Formula/erlang.rb` for you