# How to prevent homebrew from upgrading a package?

Tags: homebrew

I'm wondering if there's any means to prevent Homebrew from upgrading a particular package ? Yesterday I went for a `brew upgrade` which updated the lua package from 5.1 to 5.2. It broke one of the projects I'm working on those days so I had to downgrade the lua package today when I noticed it.

I'd like this not to happen again, and I guess Homebrew must provide this kind of feature, but I didn't find anything about it in the documentation. Do you have any clue ?

Comment: you can install specific version of packages : more info on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore formula on brew upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093918/ignore-formula-on-brew-upgrade)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`brew pin someformula`.

There is also a `lua51` formula now.

Comment: @Oderdra this is a valid answer. Although I´m struggling to find a link which documents `brew pin` it is there and does solve the OP´s issue.

Comment: from the output of `man brew`: `Pin the specified formulae, preventing them from being upgraded when issuing the brew upgrade command without arguments. See also unpin.`

Comment: @Odedra it does provide an accurate answer to my question. But I'm struggling as well to find some documentation, apart from the man. One should never forget the man files !

Comment: Yea, I guess I should've looked a bit more of the details of  ``brew pin`` before running ``brew upgrade $(brew outdated)``, because that *does* include an argument, and so the pinning is not enforced.

Answer (score 4):

`brew pin formula` works well, but [it's not currently possible to pin casks](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/90242).

I need to prevent upgrade of a particular cask, so I use a filter to ignore that cask when upgrading:

```
brew update
brew upgrade --cask `brew outdated --cask | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v cask-to-skip`
```

Comment: Since we can't currently pin casks, this seems like the only one useable when casks are your pinning target. Do watch out, though - if you typo the 'cask-to-skip', and the typo isn't in the list, it won't skip any... :)

Comment: Agree, @JesseAdelman. Luckily I'm using a script so I won't mistype it

Comment: The `--cask` option doesn't work for me when using it to search for outdated casks. You should be using `--greedy` instead. Like so: `brew upgrade --greedy \`brew outdated --greedy | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v docker\``

Comment: `--cask` has been working, and is still working for me. I agree that `--greedy` would help folks that need/want updates that are less important/official. I only want stable ones so I don't use `--greedy` for that. In your example, non-casks are also included and upgraded, which I was specifically avoiding in my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the story, for my case using opencv as an example, it means that

```
brew -v edit opencv3
brew -v fetch --deps opencv3
brew -v install --build-from-source opencv3
brew pin opencv3
```